# How to make React Rating Mui component required

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-props

The [TextField](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/text-field/) mui component has a `required` attribute that you can set that makes it required before you submit the form (a pop up appears that asks you to fill it before you submit).

I want the [Rating](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/rating/) mui component to be required but it does not have this feature, I thought about combining it to another hidden component that can be required (maybe something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63206483/7501501) answer and add a `required` there) but it does not work for me:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import Rating from "@material-ui/lab/Rating";

export default function Create() {
  const [rating, setRating] = useState();
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <FormControlLabel
            required
            control={
              <>
                <input
                  required
                  name="rating"
                  type="number"
                  value={rating}
                  ref={register}
                  hidden
                  readOnly
                />
                <Rating
                  required
                  name="rating"
                  value={rating}
                  precision={1}
                  onChange={(_, value) => {
                    setRating(value);
                  }}
                />
              </>
            }
          />
          <Button type="submit" fullWidth variant="contained" color="primary">
            Submit
          </Button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

This code lets me submit without rating.

What can I do to solve this and why `Rating` does not have a `required` prop?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [resolver](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform#resolver) from `react-hook-form` with `errors` from `react-hook-form` too. And, you can use  to validate and do that your field be required with `.required()`, for example with [Yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup).

Install yuo with this:

```
npm install yup
```

Than, do this:

```
import * as Yup from "yup";

const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  rating: Yup.number().required("Rating is required"),
});
```

And this:

```
export default function Create() {

const [rating, setRating] = useState();
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm({
    validationSchema: validationSchema
  });

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <FormControlLabel
            required
            control={
              <>
                <input
                  required
                  name="rating"
                  type="number"
                  value={rating}
                  ref={register}
                  hidden
                  readOnly
                />
                <Rating
                  required
                  name="rating"
                  value={rating}
                  precision={1}
                  onChange={(_, value) => {
                    setRating(value);
                  }}
                />
              </>
            }
          />
          {errors.rating && (
            <span style={{ color: "red" }}>{errors.rating.message}</span>
          )}
          <Button type="submit" fullWidth variant="contained" color="primary">
            Submit
          </Button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi I'm actually having a really hard time making it work, the poc I sent was just a weird test to make things work. Could you please help me create a minimal code that is simply verifying rating field? (No input and no FormControlLabel)